# 3,6V DC motor spinning with L298N and Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I'm trying to control a re used DC motor from a drill (3,6V) with a L298N and a Arduino. It's powered with a 5V - 60A power supply.

I tried to follow this step by step tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyjo_ggEtVU) but the motor is not spinning..yet. I can ear a noise, it starts to spin a micron and then stops.

I though that it could be something wrong with the power supply but I connected the 4V battery from the drill and the same thing is happening. If I connect the motor directly to the battery it is spinning nicely...

I though then that it was a code issue but I tried a no load test and measured the voltage without the motor -> I've the 4V required voltage. When the motor is connected I have 300mV instead of 4V.

Do you know what could go wrong? Is the L298 dead? just got it a few hours ago...

Would be nice if you have any clue.

Many thanks.

// Commande moteur
    int enA = 9;
    int in1 = 8;
    int in2 = 7;

```
void setup() 
{
  // Définition des sorties

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);

  //Sens de rotation du moteur

  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);

  //Vitesse de rotation du moteur

  analogWrite(enA, 200);

  //Delay

  delay(5000);

   //Arrêt du moteur

  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

[image: Wiring]

Answer (score 1):

The L239 is a terrible motor driver. It's the kind of motor driver Noah used to control The Ark.

It requires a power supply that is at least 2.5V more than the "logic input high" voltage, which is rated at 2.3V. That means an *absolute minimum* of 4.8V, which is borderline for the Arduino's 5V pin, especially if you are running off USB (which can drop as low as 4.75V and still be within specification) and *way* out when powered from the battery.  It's really designed for driving motors in the 12V+ range.

To drive a low voltage motor like yours you need to pick a more modern MOSFET based motor driver.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what if I use a 12V power supply and I use the AnalogWrite to drop the motor voltage to 4V?

Comment: It might work... until that fateful day when you accidentally send 12V straight to the motor...

Comment: I'll try that...  thanks :)

Comment: I tried with a 20V DC power supply and it's not going to work because analogWrite(pin,1) gives me a minimum of 12V DC at the motor.

Comment: Then you should get a proper motor driver that is suitable for your motor, or get a better motor that is suitable for your power supply. Matching your components to your needs is step one of learning to be an electronic engineer...